# logics need to be created for reading xml

Tags: php, xml

I have xml for restaurant menu.

```
<RestuarantMenu>
<Day name="Monday">
    <options startTime="10:00">This is first link monday</options>
    <options startTime="14:00">This is second link monday</options>
    <options startTime="20:00">This is third link monday</options>
</Day>

<Day name="Tuesday">
    <options startTime="10:00">This is first link</options>
    <options startTime="14:00">This is second link</options>
    <options startTime="20:00">This is third link</options>
</Day>
 <RestuarantMenu>
```

Now I want if current day is monday and time is between 10:00 and 14:00, out should be "this is first link monday" (first option). Similarly if current time is even greate than 20:00 and less than 10:00, it should show `last option`. (dinner menu till tomorrow morning 10:00).

Here is my PHP code.

```
echo $t=date('d-m-Y H:i:s'); echo '<br>';
echo $day = date("D",strtotime($t)); echo '<br>';
echo $time = date("H:i",strtotime($t)); echo '<br>';

$xml=simplexml_load_file("menu.xml");

foreach($xml->Day as $Day)
{
   if($Day->attributes() == 'Monday')
   {
    foreach($Day->options as $options)
    {
        if($options->attributes() < $time)
        {
            echo $options; echo '<br>';
        }

     }
    }
  }
```

For now it just find option time less than current time, but not in between etc.

Right now the condition `$options->attributes() < $time` give me that option whose time is less than current time. But if current time is 15:00, it will give me two options in output 10:00 and 14:00, but I need one that is 14:00. 
If my question is not clear, kindly ask me. 
Thanks

Comment: You simply need to keep track of the day and the time and create a date object. You aren't doing any conditional logic in there at all :S

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Pekka웃, right now the condition `$options->attributes() < $time` give me that option whose time is less than current time. But if current time is 15:00, it will give me two options in output `10:00 and 14:00`, but I need one that is `14:00`. Hope this clear it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$day = "Tuesday";
$time="09:50";

// select <option> by $day and $time
$results = $xml->xpath("/*/Day[@name = '$day']/options[translate(@startTime, ':', '') <= translate('$time',':', '')]");

$result = array_pop($results); // get last element
if (is_null($result)) $result = "the restaurant is closed!"; // if $time is smaller than any startTime

echo "$day, $time... $result";
```

see it working: https://eval.in/86906

**important note:**
This works only if the `startTime`-attributes are in ascending order.

The `xpath`-expression will select all `<option>` with `startTime` <= `$time` and store them in `array $results`, `array_pop()` takes the last element in the array and makes it `$result`.
If `$time`is < `startTime`, `$result = NULL`

the time-values are compared as numbers, the `translate`-function will change `12:00` to `1200` and `14:23` to `1423`, so `1200`< `1423`= `true`